# не работает setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

нужно что бы через определенное время анимация повторялась, делается один раз и всё

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
function swapImages() {
 $(".img-left").animate({"left": "100%"}, 1500);
 $(".img-right").animate({"left": "-80%"}, 1500);
   }
     setInterval(swapImages,2000);
});
```

```css
.img-left {
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -54%;
    
}
.img-right {
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-left">
  <img src="https://2oq.ru/test/img/small_red.png">
</div>
<div class="img-right">
  <img src="https://2oq.ru/test/img/big_red.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Восстановите первоначальные значения свойств, чтобы было что анимировать:

```
function swapImages() {
  $(".img-left").css("left", "");
  $(".img-right").css("left", "");
  $(".img-left").animate({"left": "100%"}, 1500);
  $(".img-right").animate({"left": "-80%"}, 1500);
}
```

Comment: спасибо то что нужно